# Spying on function within a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, require, sinon, chai

I have some code that looks like this, in a file called logger.ts

```
(function (logger) {
logger.getLogger = function () {
    var log4js = require('log4js');
    log4js.configure(__dirname + "/../log4js-config.json");
    var logger = log4js.getLogger(require('path').basename(__filename));
    return logger;
};
})(module.exports);
```

Now, the logger that gets returned here is an object that contains methods such as 'info' and 'error'.  I want to spy on these methods and assert that they were called with certain parameters.

I use this code in other classes and want to mock and spy on the 'error' and 'info' methods.  I have therefore written this in my test

```
var loggerStub = require('logger');
sinon.spy(loggerStub.getLogger, 'info');

it("should log the query", function() {
            var spyCall = loggerStub.info.getCall(0);
            expect(spyCall.args[0]).deep.equal("error: " + somethingVariable);
        });
```

Running this gives me the error:

```
Attempted to wrap undefined property info as function.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spying on a property (`info`) of your own function (`getLogger`) which you never set instead of the `log4js.info`.

A fast way (not sure if thats good for you) to solve this, is to actually create the logger and spy in the returned objects info method:

```
var logger = require('logger').getLogger(); // be aware that an actual logger is created!
sinon.spy(logger, 'info');

it("should log the query", function() {
            var spyCall = logger.info.getCall(0);
            expect(spyCall.args[0]).deep.equal("error: " + somethingVariable);
        });
```